# How to create a unit vector of AB towards a number of degrees and calculate the angle between them?

Tags: python, math, vector, angle, degrees

Here you can see the Vector AB.

Goal: Make Vector AC to find out α

Problem: To find out the angle α I would first need a second vector AC that must point towards 190° and has the same length as the unit vector of AB. How do I create that Vector?

```
            A = (5, 10)
            B = (10, 5)

            distance = np.array([B[0] - A[0], A[1] - B[1]]) # Vector from A to B
            unit_vector = distance / np.linalg.norm(distance) # unit vector

            # Need to make Vector AC here

            # Get angle between vector AB and vector AC
            AB = unit_vector(unit_vector)
            AC = unit_vector(c)
            print(np.arccos(np.clip(np.dot(AB, AC), -1.0, 1.0)))
```

[image: Idea]

Comment: Unclear question.

Comment: OK, so this is obviously homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: Are you having problems with the code or the math? If code you should post what you have and go in detail about what issue you have. If not then SO is not the right place to post.

Comment: Traditionally, in a Cartesian plane, 0 degrees points to the right.

Comment: You don't really need a unit vector.  If you subtract A from B, you'll get dx,dy.   The arctangent of dy/dx gives you the angle from 0 (to the right) to AB.  You'll have to adjust for quadrants, unless you use `math.atan2`.

Comment: @SibtainReza I am aware that the question might be hard to understand I am not sure how else I would ask it. I will edit the picture in a second and maybe that will clarify the question. Im sorry!

Comment: Edit to picture: I want to draw the Vector AC so I could calculate the angle of α

Comment: The issue is, what do you expect the output to be?  Is it just an angle measurement in radians?  You can find the theta for AB with arctangent.  Then, all you have to do is subtract that from 190 (well, modulo the degrees/radians conversions).

Comment: @TimRoberts Does it matter whether it's homework or not? Anyway, I have an Object A and I am trying to found out whether the Object A is moving towards Object B. By making the Vector AC I could find out the angle α and if that angle is α<0.001 then I could make sure that Object A is moving towards Object B. That is the goal.

Comment: @TimRoberts I understand that traditionally the 0 degrees point to the right but the solution to the problem requires that the degrees point to the top and go counter clock wise

Comment: @takendarkk I have added the code that I have so far. I hope this clarifies the question! If its still not understandable please let me know.

Comment: @Dani_K -- Yes, it matters, because it is unethical for us to do your homework for you.  Now that you have provided some code, we'll all feel a lot better about helping.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm sorry I didnt think about that. It's actually just a private project where im trying to create a bot that can track if an object inside a video game flies towards object B. So no homework or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, look at this.  Given your points (5,10) and (10,5):

```
C:\tmp>python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math

## Find the angle to AB using traditional 0-to-the-right axes.

>>> math.atan2(-5,5)
-0.7853981633974483

## Convert to degrees.

>>> math.atan2(-5,5) * 180 / math.pi
-45.0

## Subtract 90 to shift the 0 point to the north

>>> math.atan2(-5,5) * 180 / math.pi - 90
-135.0

## Modulo 360 to make it positive

>>> (math.atan2(-5,5) * 180 / math.pi - 90) % 360
225.0

##  Subtract 190, and we get the value for the angle alpha.

>>> (math.atan2(-5,5) * 180 / math.pi - 90) % 360 - 190
35.0
```